# Moving files from Desktop to another folder and vice versa using AppleScript (and bash inside of Applescript) inside Automator

Tags: applescript, command-line, automator

I need to move files from my desktop to a folder `~/Documents/Desktop migration` and I have tried to code a script which will do that. Unfortunately, (and the reason why I'm asking here) it doesn't work.

I am using a service (so that I can go to any application's menu bar > Services > (insert name of service here) ) and need to store the variable data, so I think automator is suited for the job, and I'm using AppleScript and Terminal to move.

What doesn't work is it only transfers files to the desktop from the Desktop Migration folder and not back from the desktop to the Desktop Migration folder, so **how can I achieve this**?

What I've come up with so far:
[image]

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set theQuery to input
    if theQuery = 1 then
        do shell script "mv ~/Desktop/* ~/Documents/Desktop\\ migration"
        set output to 0
        return output
    else if theQuery = 0 then
        do shell script "mv ~/Documents/Desktop\\ migration/* ~/Desktop"
        set output to 1
        return output
    end if
end run
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like you'er trying to set a *flag* that toggles each time the *Service* runs, and there is more than one way to accomplish this.

In this example, I created an **Automator** *Service* named **Test Service**, with the *settings* shown in the image below, and added a **Run Shell Script** *action*, as this is all you should need to accomplish the task since you were using a `do shell script` **AppleScript** *command* anyway to do the *work*.

[image: Automator Service]

As presently coded, each time the *Service* runs it says what the *flag* is set to, 0 or 1, and sets it to the opposite. You'd of course remove the `say...` *commands* replacing them with the *code* you want to run based on the setting of the *flag*.

```
#!/bin/bash

file="$HOME/Library/Services/Test Service.workflow"

flag="$(xattr -l "$file" | awk '/com.TestService.flag/{print $2}')"

if [[ $flag -eq 0 ]]; then
    # Do something...

    say "flag is currently set to 0, setting flag to 1"

        # Set flag to 1.
    xattr -w com.TestService.flag 1 "$file"
else
    # Do something else...

    say "flag is currently set to 1, setting flag to 0"

        # Set flag to 0.
    xattr -w com.TestService.flag 0 "$file"
fi
```

---

This uses `xattr` to set an *extended attribute* on the **Automator's** *Service* `.workflow` *file* and it is this that is read each time and changed each time the *Service* is run and this is the *flag* to determine which *branch* of the `if` *statement* runs in the *script*.

You can either manually set the `com.TestService.flag` using `xattr` in **Terminal** before you run the *saved* **Automator's** *Service* so as to have the *extended attribute* applied to is `.workflow` *file* or if you just run the *saved* **Automator's** *Service* the first time is will set it to `1` as it reads the empty `flag` *variable* the first time as being equal to `0`.

The following *output* from **Terminal** shows the *extended attributes* of the **Automator's** *Service* `.workflow` *file* when it was first saved, it just had the `com.apple.FinderInfo` *attribute* set, and then the *Service* was run a couple of times to show that the `com.TestService.flag` *attribute* was set and changed each time the *Service* was run. (I manually ran the `xattr` *command* before and then in-between each time I ran the *Service* to have this *output* to show.)

---

```
$ xattr -l "$HOME/Library/Services/Test Service.workflow"
com.apple.FinderInfo:
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020
$ xattr -l "$HOME/Library/Services/Test Service.workflow"
com.apple.FinderInfo:
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020
com.TestService.flag: 1
$ xattr -l "$HOME/Library/Services/Test Service.workflow"
com.apple.FinderInfo:
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020
com.TestService.flag: 0
$
```

---

Obviously you can change the name of the *flag* from `com.TestService.flag` to whatever you'd like however remember to change it in the *script* in all three places, in the `awk` *command* and in each `xattr` *command* in each *branch* of the `if` *statement*. Also change the name of the `file` *variable* as appropriate for the actual *name* of your **Automator** *Service* `.workflow` *file*.

Comment: I'm actually testing the OP's bogus "solution" and your solution in a Sierra VM

Comment: @klanomath, It works in macOS Sierra. I wrote it in OS X 10.8.5, as you can tell from the picture of Automator, but tested in macOS afterwards. :)

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. The `say` commands are also well-thought in case I needed to troubleshoot.

Answer (score -1):

Try with a Terminal command, it’s very simple·

Type rsync -av, press once the space bar and drag the folder to the Terminal window. Drag the destination folder to the window and hit Return.

That’s it !.

The original folder (files) remains intact in their position.